# Flutter Upload image with MultipartRequest inside specific body

Tags: flutter

I need to upload a list of attachments inside an array with this structure:

```
[
'description' => ['sometimes', 'string'],
'attachments' => ['sometimes', 'array'],
'attachments.*.file' => ['required', 'file'],
]
```

I'm using package http, and to upload files only allow me to put inside 'files', i'm using this code and it works to upload a file inside files, but I need that structure.

```
 if (json != null) {
      request.fields.addAll(json);
    }

    for (var item in filesPath) {
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'file',
        item,
      ));
    }
```

There is any way to achieve this with this plugin ?

Comment: based on my experience bit difficult using multipart with `http` plugin,
if only 1 image, maybe you can convert image to `base64` . then post `json` like usual

Comment: @pmatatias thanks for help, i'm gonna switch to dio instead

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
void uploadImage() async {
  // Show loader
  // open a byteStream
  var stream = new
  http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(file.openRead()));
  // get file length
  var length = await file.length();
  Map<String, String> headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": token
  }; // ignore this headers if there is no authentication

  // string to uri
  var uri = Uri.parse(Constants.BASE_URL);

  // create multipart request
  var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

  // if you need more parameters to parse, add those like this 
  // to the API request
  request.fields["orderId"] = orderID.toString();

  // multipart that takes file.. here this "file" is a key of the 
 // API request
  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream,
      length,
      filename: basename(file.path));

  //add headers
  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  // add file to multipart
  request.files.add(multipartFile);

  // send request to upload image
  await request.send().then((response) async {
    // listen for response
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
      setState(() {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print('uploaded');
        } else {
          print('failed');
        }
      });

      // Hide loader

    });
  }).catchError((e) {
    print(e);
    // Hide loader
  });
```

Comment: that will do the same as I have. i'm gonna switch to dio instead